# Visual Basics: Writing to a text file not working

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make a coin counter that counts coins and writes the total to a text file.
I feel like this should work, but it's not coming together.  Is anyone able to tell me where I am going wrong?

My code:

```
Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
    Dim intCoin As Integer
    Dim intNickelCount As Integer
    Dim intDimeCount As Integer
    Dim intQuarterCount As Integer
    Dim intTotal As Integer
    Dim intNickelTotal As Integer
    Dim intDimeTotal As Integer
    Dim intQuarterTotal As Integer
    Dim decTotal As Decimal


    file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("C:\Users\O'Death\Documents\test.txt", True)
        Do While intCoin <> -1
            intCoin = CInt(InputBox("Enter a coin value as 5, 10, or 25...Enter a -1 to stop data entry", "Coin Values Data Entry"))
            If intCoin = 5 Then
                intNickelCount += 1
                intNickelTotal = intTotal + intCoin
            ElseIf intCoin = 10 Then
                intDimeCount += 1
                intDimeTotal = intDimeCount + intCoin
            ElseIf intCoin = 25 Then
                intQuarterCount += 1
                intQuarterTotal = intQuarterCount + intCoin
                If intCoin = -1 Then
                    file.WriteLine("There are ", intQuarterTotal, " quarters", intDimeCount, " dimes ", ", and ", intNickelTotal, "nickels.")
                End If
            End If
        Loop
    decTotal = (intQuarterCount * 0.25) + (intDimeCount * 0.1) + (intNickelCount * 0.05)
    file.WriteLine(decTotal)
    FileClose()

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim file As System.IO.StreamReader
    file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader("C:\Users\O'Death\Documents\test.txt")

End Sub
```

Comment: Use be file.Close() instead of FileClose(), learn the Using statement

Comment: What exactly is not working?  Show us some inputs and outputs that you're getting along with what you are expecting to get instead.

Comment: Also, just looking at (or telling us about) the final output is not enough. You need to actually debug the code, i.e. set a breakpoint at the top and step through it line by line. You should know exactly what you expect to happen at every step and so you should be able to see exactly where and how the actual behaviour differs from your expectations. That should give you a good chance of fixing the problem on your own. Even if you can't, at least you can provide us with a better explanation than "here's my code, it doesn't work".

Comment: What happens if someone has a dollar coin?  Or a loonie?  Also, it is impossible to get "True" to the last if statement.  You need to rethink the logic.

Comment: Ok thank you, I will redress it.  This is all new to me. Sorry, if it is lacking info, really appreciate all of your input. :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using streams which need to be disposed, I used the .net `File` class which can be accessed in `System.IO`. You will need to add

```
Imports System.IO
```

to the top of the file with the other Imports.

You had too many variables which probably helped with the confusion. You only need varaibles to hold the accumulation of count values and one to hold the total value. I dimmed the intCoin in the loop.

I changed the series of `ElseIf`'s to a `Select Case` block. A bit easier to read.

I used a `StringBuilder` to build the input for the file. It really isn't necessary for this code (I think it is good for 10 or over string pieces) but I thought I would introduce you to this class.

I used an interpolated string to build the input for the file. This is indicated by the dollar sign (`$`) preceding the string. We can then add variables in line surrounded by braces `{ }`. The `:C2` after the `decTotal` tells the compiler to produce a string in Currency format with 2 decimal places.

Finally we write to the file with `File.WriteAllText`. This creates the file if it doesn't exist  (If it does exist, the contents will be overwritten) , writes to the file, and closes the file.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim intNickelCount As Integer
    Dim intDimeCount As Integer
    Dim intQuarterCount As Integer
    Dim decTotal As Decimal
    Do
        Dim intCoin = CInt(InputBox("Enter a coin value as 5, 10, or 25...Enter a -1 to stop data entry", "Coin Values Data Entry"))
        Select Case intCoin
            Case -1
                Exit Do
            Case 5
                intNickelCount += 1
            Case 10
                intDimeCount += 1
            Case 25
                intQuarterCount += 1
            Case Else
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Entry. Please try again")
        End Select
    Loop
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    sb.AppendLine($"There are {intQuarterCount} quarters, {intDimeCount} dimes, and {intNickelCount} nickels.")
    decTotal = CDec((intQuarterCount * 0.25) + (intDimeCount * 0.1) + (intNickelCount * 0.05))
    sb.AppendLine($"The total value is {decTotal:C2}")
    File.WriteAllText("C:\Users\O'Death\Documents\test.txt", sb.ToString)
End Sub
```